# Using FormWizard trying to create bookmarks to relevant questions

Tags: jquery, formwizard

Afternoon/Morning

Im using the Jquery formwizard which has 10 questions

1. First question
2. Second question
3. Third question
   etc all the way to question 10

Im trying to create a bookmark down the side so the user can jump back and forth from the questions with out having to press the next/previous buttons, but im having a small issues trying to get it to work...

below is how the form wizard is laid out i havent posted all 10 questions because i dont want to clog this page up but please see the below 3 questions

```
<a href="#" id="lnk3" style="color:Black">Go to Question 3</a>
      <div id="feedbackform">
            <fieldset class="sectionwrap" id="Q1">
                <legend>Question 1</legend>
                <p>
                    Which one of this five words means the same as <strong>TIRED</strong>? Write the number in the Answer
                    Square.</p>
                <ol>
                    <li>LATE</li>
                    <li>CLIMB</li>
                    <li>HEAVY</li>
                    <li>WEARY</li>
                    <li>SLOW</li>
                </ol>
                <p style="margin-left:-5%">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Q1Answer" runat="server" class="TextBox" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="sectionwrap" id="Q2">
                <legend>Question 2</legend>
                <p>
                    One of these numbers is wrong, because is does not follow the regular order of the
                    other numbers in the row.<br />
                    <br />
                    Write the number which is wrong in the Answer Square</p>
                <p style="margin-left: 32%">
                    <strong>2 4 6 8 10 11 14 16</strong>
                </p>
                <div class="WhiteSpace">
                </div>
                <p style="margin-left: -5%">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Q2Answer" runat="server" class="TextBox" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="sectionwrap" id="Q3">
                <legend>Question 3</legend>
                <p>
                    LID is related to BOX as CORK is related to......?<br />
                    <br />
                    Write the number of the correct word in the Answer Square.
                </p>
                <ol>
                    <li>WATER</li>
                    <li>LIFE BELT</li>
                    <li>BOTTLE</li>
                    <li>TREE</li>
                    <li>FLOAT</li>
                </ol>
                <p style="margin-left: -5%">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Q3Answer" runat="server" class="TextBox" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
    </div>
```

as you can see i have a href at the top with an id of lnk3 when the user clicks this im trying to get the formwizard to go to question 3.

This is my Jquery where im capturing the click of the link

```
   $("a[ID='lnk3']").live('click', function()
   {
     $('#feedbackform>Fieldset>ID=Q3');

    });
```

But sadly its not working? please bare in mind the formwizard is a plugin which im sure you already new iv tried created a JSFiddle but sadly i cant get the formwizard plugin on it, you can see an example of the formqizard here http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/formwizard.htm

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

elements can be selected directly by using their IDs, use `on` instead of `live` which is deprecated, and you can try `offset` and `scrollTop`;

```
$("#lnk3").on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var t = $('#Q3').offset().top;
   $(window).scrollTop(t)
});
```

Comment: sorry didnt see the rest, hang on ill try

Comment: Doesnt seem to be doing anything, i click the link and nothing happens?

Comment: @ScottAtkinson is your fieldset positioned relatively?

Comment: This is what i have in the FormWizard style sheet /*fieldset that wraps around each form "page" */
fieldset.sectionwrap{ border-width:0;padding:5px;height:300px;width:700px;} so the answer to your question is no

Comment: @ScottAtkinson so try `fieldset {position: relative}`

Comment: @ScottAtkinson are you sure script is running? try alerting something within the click handler.

Comment: @ScottAtkinson this works only when the page has scrollbar try this: http://jsfiddle.net/vXHsP/

Comment: My page hasnt got a scroll bar, i put a link in my post showing how the form wizard is laid out, it scrolls from left to right depending on what button is pressed i.e Next/Preivous